# accessing a specific leaf-list entry using yang restconf

Tags: ietf-netmod-yang, ietf-restconf

It  is clear to me how to refer to a `list` item (restconf draft) but it is not clear how to refer to a specific `leaf-list entry`. 
For example, given the following definition:

```
module x { 
   container y { 
     leaf-list z;
   }
}

and if I have the following data in the system

<y>
  <z>a</z>
  <z>b</z>
  <z>d</z>
</y>
```

how do I insert a `c` in the third position ?

Restconf has the 'insert' and 'point' that takes the resource uri.
But, what is the resource uri to identify a leaf-list item ?
If I want to refer to the second entry, is the following valid ?

```
/y/z=b
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each leaf-list entry is a separate data resource in restconf-draft-10.

> Containers,
> leafs, leaf-list entries, list entries, anydata and anyxml nodes are
> data resources.

This is what [Section 3.5](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-netconf-restconf-10#section-3.5) says about `leaf-list` entries. Further it defines encoding of `leaf-list` Data Resource Identifiers in 5.3.1:

> If a data node in the path expression is a YANG leaf-list node, then
> the leaf-list value MUST be encoded according to the following rules:

> o  The instance-identifier for the leaf-list MUST be encoded using
> one path segment [RFC3986].

> o  The path segment is constructed by having the leaf-list name,
> followed by an "=" character, followed by the leaf-list value.
> (e.g., /restconf/data/top-leaflist=fred).

So, your example for second entry it would be: `/restconf/data/x:y/z=b`.

As for inserting, it seems to be unclear. There are examples in the appendix D of the draft for both `point` and `insert`, but use a `list` instead of a `leaf-list` (note that both MUST be `ordered-by user` in order for the two parameters to be valid in a request).

[D.3.5.  "point" Parameter](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-netconf-restconf-10#appendix-D.3.5)

```
  POST /restconf/data/example-jukebox:jukebox/
      library/artist=Foo%20Fighters/album=Wasting%20Light?
      insert=after&point=%2Fexample-jukebox%3Ajukebox%2F
      library%2Fartist%3DFoo%20Fighters%2Falbum%3D
      Wasting%20Light%2Fsong%3DBridge%20Burning   HTTP/1.1
  Host: example.com
  Content-Type: application/yang.data+json

  {
    "example-jukebox:song" : {
      "name" : "Rope",
      "location" : "/media/foo/a7/rope.mp3",
      "format" : "MP3",
      "length" : 259
    }
  }
```

Comment: How can i access both z.a and z.b, I tried using comma but it throws error as "unsupported uri format - number of values differs from number of keys"